# How to get back result as returned object type when executing script as PowerShell.exe -File

Tags: powershell

If I have a script (script.ps1) like below:

```
$dir = Get-Item "C:\Windows"
$dir
```

and if I call it like:

```
$myDir = "script.ps1"
```

I get back the `$dir` object in `$myDir` and if I use:

```
$myDir.Name
```

I get:

```
Windows
```

I have a scenario where I need to call scripts using

```
$myDir = Powershell.exe -File "script.ps1"
```

With this, I end up getting the output in the form of a string array object and not in the form of the script-returned object as the command is apparently executed in a different session. Due to this, I can't call any property. E.g: `$myDir.Name` returns nothing

My question is, how do I get the returned object type back as the result in the above case. i.e, even when I execute

```
$myDir = Powershell.exe -File "script.ps1"
```

`$myDir.Name` should return `Windows`. Is it even possible?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show your code in script.ps1 and if you want full directory you need to use `$myDir.FullName`

Comment: Script.ps1 contains the same two lines mentioned at the top of the post.

The confusion is not about which property to call. When I call the script using `PowerShell.exe - File` the object won't have any property at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this :

**script.ps1** (returns value of `$dir`):

```
$dir = Get-Item "C:\Windows"
return $dir
```

**script2.ps1** (returns name of `$dir`) :

```
$myDir = .\script.ps1
$myDir.Name
```

`$myDir.Name` returns : `Windows`

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, I am not looking at a different value from the output. I am looking at getting the same object when calling using `Powershell.exe -File`. I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: You can't call `Powershell.exe -File` in a variable. Call the script from another script with `.\script.ps1` (means they are in the same root). I changed `FullName` by `Name`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -OutputFormat parameter of powershell.exe.

```
#Write the command to file
"get-item c:\windows\" | out-file C:\temp\test.ps1
$justastring = powershell.exe -file c:\temp\test.ps1
#this is a string array
$justastring | get-member
$notastring = powershell.exe -outputformat xml -file c:\temp\test.ps1
#this is a Deserialized.System.IO.DirectoryInfo
$notastring | get-member
```

This output is also able to be saved as a file and brought back in later. See [Import-CliXml](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176873.aspx) and [Export-CliXml](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176824.aspx). Note that because they are serialized objects they are no longer "live". Some of the methods you are used to seeing will not be there, property values will no longer update either. Its essentially a snapshot of the command output at the instant that the command ran.